# About preserving real-rootedness of multivariable polynomials

Tags: fa.functional-analysis, real-analysis, polynomials, real-algebraic-geometry, differential-calculus

Say $f_i(z_1,z_2,..,z_m)$ are polynomials real rooted in the $z$s for a bunch of polynomials indexed by $i$. When can one say that $\sum_{i} p_i f_i(z_1,z_2,..,z_m)$ is also real rooted?

---

If necessary assume that,

- $\sum_i p_i = 1$
- Each $f_i$ is of bounded degree in each $z_k$. 
  Say assume that each $z_k$ occurs with atmost quadratic power in any $f_i$.

Answer (score 4):

Consider the univariate case:

In general, a linear combination of real-rooted polynomials is not real-rooted: Let $f_1=(z+1)^2$ and $f_2=(z-1)^2$. Every convex combination of $f_1,f_2$ which is not $f_1$ or $f_2$ is not real rooted.

Here are some positive criteria:

Assume that the $f_i$ have a common interlacer and that they have positive leading coeficient, then every convex combination is real-rooted. See http://arxiv.org/abs/1304.4132 for the definitions (text after Lemma 4.2).

If we have just two univariate polynomials $f$ and $g$, then every linear combination is real rooted if and only if $f$ and $g$ are real rooted and interlace each other.

For more than one variable you have to specify what you mean by real rooted: Every nonconstant polynomial in more than one variable has nonreal roots.

Comment: The paper you linked to is only about univariate polynomials. (But do you have a reference to a proof of it?) I have asked a related question here on which may be you can shed some light, http://mathoverflow.net/questions/198354/about-real-roots-of-complex-multivariable-polynomials

Comment: @Hans Would you know if there is any multivariable analogue of this statement?

Comment: @user6818: I think the proof should work with similar techniques as in this paper. at the moment I have no reference.

Comment: @guest: one way to generalize realrootedness to more variables is the concept of hyperbolic polynomials. you can define the interlacing property for them too (for example http://arxiv.org/abs/1212.6696). and most of what I've written should extend to that case.

Comment: I will look at your related question, but I can't promise anything.

Answer (score 1):

The complete answer to when and how linear operations on coeffcients of a multivariate polynomial preserve stability is answered in [[1](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0401)] (with more applications of the ideas in [[2](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3087)]), and using those results an answer for the OP should follow.

[1]. Julius Borcea, Petter Brändén. [The Lee-Yang and Pólya-Schur Programs. I. Linear Operators Preserving Stability](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.0401), (2009).

[2]. Julius Borcea, Petter Brändén. [The Lee-Yang and Pólya-Schur Programs. II. Theory of Stable Polynomials and Applications](http://arxiv.org/abs/0809.3087), (2008)